Как с помощью кнопки сбрасывать значение QLabel?
Делаю программу-калькулятор, в которой пользователь может подсчитать свою прибыль в игре.
Вопрос: хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на pushButton_2 сбрасывалось значение у all_profit_label до нуля.
Попытался сделать сам, выдает ошибку "'Int' object is not callable"
Код:
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.add_functions()
        
        self.load_settings()

        self.res_profit()

        self.reset_profit()

    def res_profit(self):
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.reset_profit)       

    def reset_profit(self):
        try:
            reset_all_profit = int(0)
            self.all_profit_label.setNum(reset_all_profit())
        except Exception as e:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 
                'Внимание! Что-то пошло не так!', 
                f'{e}')


martysue3005, sorry, вы не ответили мне на вопрос, который я спрашивал у вас в последнем комментарии вашего предыдущего вопроса, почему?

S. Nick, это связано с тем, что когда ты заходишь на сайт, вопрос можно задать введя только отображаемое имя и почту, таким образом я и задал тот вопрос

S. Nick, а потом нажал на кнопку "Завершить регистрацию" указав пароль и другие данные, после чего аккаунт с которого я сейчас пишу по факту заменил тот

S. Nick, это ответ на то, что вы спросили в комментариях другого вопроса

S. Nick, помогите мне пожалуйста с этим вопросом

martysue3005, я то вам сейчас помогу, но вы, пожалуйста, всегда отвечайте на вопросы, которые вам задают или просто напишите, например:  "@S.Nick не задавайте мне глупых вопросов." и я никогда у вас больше ничего не спрошу.

@S. Nick, с удовольствием буду отвечать на ваши вопросы, просто я не всегда в сети.

martysue3005,  если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете,
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Если вы, при нажатии кнопки, хотите только сбросить значение all_profit_label, 
то замените в методе res_profit():
    self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.reset_profit)   

на:
    self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.all_profit_label.setText("0"))

а метод reset_profit() уберите вообще.
main.py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(300, 400)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 120, 20))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("font: 13pt \".AppleSystemUIFont\";")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 65, 160, 20))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(119, 221, 119);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 120, 120, 20))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.all_profit_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.all_profit_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(145, 120, 120, 20))
        self.all_profit_label.setObjectName("all_profit_label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 160, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 300, 24))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "PerekupCalculator | v. 1.0.0"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите сумму:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Заработано всего:"))
        self.all_profit_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)                            
# +++        
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Обнулить ...', self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 95, 160, 20))
# !!!        
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.all_profit_label.setText("0"))  
 
        self.add_functions()
        self.load_settings()

    def load_settings(self):
        settings = QtCore.QSettings(
            "q1582187_settings.ini", QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat) 
        self.all_profit_label.setText(settings.value('all_profit_label', "0"))

    def save_settings(self):
        settings = QtCore.QSettings(
            "q1582187_settings.ini", QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat)
        settings.setValue("all_profit_label", self.all_profit_label.text())

    def closeEvent(self, event):
            self.save_settings()
            event.accept()
  
    def add_functions(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_profit)
        self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.pushButton.click)
        self.lineEdit.setFocus()

    def add_profit(self):
        try:
            all_profit = int(self.all_profit_label.text()) + \
                         int(self.lineEdit.text())
            self.all_profit_label.setNum(all_profit)
            self.lineEdit.clear()
            self.lineEdit.setFocus()            
        except Exception as e:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 
                'Внимание! Что-то пошло не так!', 
                f'{e}')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet("""
        #all_profit_label {
            font-size: 13pt;
            color: #C81912;
        }
        """)
    w = MainWindow()                                           
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


